# How to hide youtube iframe using CSS

Tags: css, iframe, youtube

My site is optimized for desktop and mobile. Most of my post has youtube videos. I like to hide Youtube videos in my mobile site since it kills the design.

Here is the sample Youtube Embed code...

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0IiB2rNSFfM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I tried using the following CSS in mobile site...

```
iframe{
    display:none;
}
```

This code hides youtube videos as well as ads in mobile site...

Please help me to how to hide only youtube videos using CSS???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) { iframe { display:none; }}
```

You should set `min-width` to value of width of devices/mobiles you want to hide iframe in.

Note that you can have multiple media queries for different screen sizes.

**More Info:**

- http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/

Comment: thanks for the reaply... i hope this code will hide all iframes in my site... but i want to hide only youtube iframe... i don't want to hide other iframes in my site (ads)...

Comment: @user723805: You can apply a class to youtube iframe like `class="youtube"` and then frame css, you can do: `iframe.youtube { display:none; }`

Comment: I already thought about this, but the problem is i have more than 100 posts with videos out of 850 posts... is there any other ways to fix the problem ??

Comment: @user723805: Then you can use jQuery like this, it will automatically add that class to only youtube iframes: `$('iframe[src*="youtube"]').addClass('youtube')` and then use css that i showed in previous comment.